# Sqlite update error no such column

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update an element on android app using sqlite as database. But I am getting the error SQLite Exception: no such column.

My logcat is:

```
04-15 18:46:19.277    5290-5290/com.example.testlayout.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testlayout.app, PID: 5290
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: id (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE pontos SET Estado=?,Armadura=?,Observações=?,Serial=?,NrColuna=?,Rede=?,Lampada=?,tir=?,Y=?,Potencia=?,X=?,Coluna=? WHERE id=?
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1572)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1520)
            at com.example.testlayout.app.PointsDBAdapter.updatePoint(PointsDBAdapter.java:85)
            at com.example.testlayout.app.CreatePoint$1.onClick(CreatePoint.java:75)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Will also share to you my publicAdapter which has the update Class:

```
public class PointsDBAdapter {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private PointsDB points;
    private String[] allColumns = {PointsDB.ID, PointsDB.SERIAL, PointsDB.OBSERVATIONS, PointsDB.TIR, PointsDB.X, PointsDB.Y,
    PointsDB.NETWORKNUMBER, PointsDB.POTENCIA, PointsDB.COLUMNNR, PointsDB.COLUNA, PointsDB.LAMP, PointsDB.ARMOR, PointsDB.LAMPSTATE};

    public PointsDBAdapter(Context context) {
            points = new PointsDB(context);
            open();
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = points.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public Point createPoint(String Serial, String Observation, boolean tir, double x, double y, int networkNumber, int intensity,
                                int ColumnNr, int Column, int lamp, int armor, int lampState) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PointsDB.SERIAL, Serial);
        values.put(PointsDB.OBSERVATIONS, Observation);
        values.put(PointsDB.TIR, tir);
        values.put(PointsDB.X, x);
        values.put(PointsDB.Y, y);
        values.put(PointsDB.NETWORKNUMBER, networkNumber);
        values.put(PointsDB.POTENCIA, intensity);
        values.put(PointsDB.COLUMNNR, ColumnNr);
        values.put(PointsDB.COLUNA, Column);
        values.put(PointsDB.LAMP, lamp);
        values.put(PointsDB.ARMOR, armor);
        values.put(PointsDB.LAMPSTATE, lampState);
        long insertId = database.insert(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        // To show how to query

        Cursor cursor = database.query(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, PointsDB.ID + " = " +
                insertId, null,null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursorToPoint(cursor);
    }

    private Point cursorToPoint(Cursor cursor) {
        Point point = new
                Point(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(3)), Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4)),
                Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(5)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(9)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(10)),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(11)), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(12)));
        return point;
    }

    public void updatePoint(int idPoint, String Serial, String Observation, boolean tir, double x, double y, int networkNumber, int intensity,
                            int ColumnNr, int Column, int lamp, int armor, int lampState){
        String where = "id=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(idPoint)};
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PointsDB.SERIAL, Serial);
        values.put(PointsDB.OBSERVATIONS, Observation);
        values.put(PointsDB.TIR, tir);
        values.put(PointsDB.X, x);
        values.put(PointsDB.Y, y);
        values.put(PointsDB.NETWORKNUMBER, networkNumber);
        values.put(PointsDB.POTENCIA, intensity);
        values.put(PointsDB.COLUMNNR, ColumnNr);
        values.put(PointsDB.COLUNA, Column);
        values.put(PointsDB.LAMP, lamp);
        values.put(PointsDB.ARMOR, armor);
        values.put(PointsDB.LAMPSTATE, lampState);
        database.update(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
    }

    public Point getPoint(int idPoint){
        Log.d("tag", "estou a entrar com um valor de idPoint = " + idPoint);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, PointsDB.ID + " = " +
                idPoint, null,null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            return cursorToPoint(cursor);
        } else
            return null;
    }

    public long count() {
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(database,PointsDB.TABLE_NAME);
    }
}
```

This is my DBhelper Class:

```
public class PointsDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String SERIAL = "Serial";
    public static final String OBSERVATIONS = "Observações";
    public static final String TIR = "tir";
    public static final String X = "X";
    public static final String Y = "Y";
    public static final String NETWORKNUMBER = "Rede";
    public static final String POTENCIA = "Potencia";
    public static final String COLUMNNR = "NrColuna";
    public static final String COLUNA = "Coluna";
    public static final String LAMP = "Lampada";
    public static final String ARMOR = "Armadura";
    public static final String LAMPSTATE = "Estado";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pontos.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "pontos";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_NAME + "( " + ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + SERIAL
            + " text not null, " + OBSERVATIONS + " text not null, "
            + TIR + " text not null" +
            ", " + X + " text not null, " + Y + " text not null, " + NETWORKNUMBER + " text not null, " + POTENCIA + " text not null, "
            + COLUMNNR + " text not null, " + COLUNA + " text not null, " + LAMP + " text not null, "
            + ARMOR + " text not null, " + LAMPSTATE + " text not null);";

    public PointsDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(PointsDB.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data"
        );
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

And finally this is where I call the method in my main class:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                    String Serial = SerialField.getText().toString();
                    String Observation = ObservationField.getText().toString();
                    double X = Double.parseDouble(XField.getText().toString());
                    double Y = Double.parseDouble(YField.getText().toString());
                    int columnNumber = Integer.parseInt(columnNrField.getText().toString());
                    int intensity = Integer.parseInt(intensityField.getText().toString());
                    int networkToSet = networkSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    boolean checkBoxStatus = status.isChecked();
                    int valToSet = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    int setColumn = columnSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    int setArmor = armor.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    int setLamp = lamp.getSelectedItemPosition();

                        pointsList.updatePoint(pos, Serial, Observation, checkBoxStatus, X, Y, networkToSet, columnNumber, intensity, setColumn, setArmor, setLamp, valToSet);
```

Comment: try uninstall and re-install of app or change the database version and run again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seen to me that your column name is _id and not id.]

As you can check here.

```
public static final String ID = "_id";
```

and here

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_NAME + "( " + ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + SERIAL
            + " text not null, " + OBSERVATIONS + " text not null, "
            + TIR + " text not null" +
            ", " + X + " text not null, " + Y + " text not null, " + NETWORKNUMBER + " text not null, " + POTENCIA + " text not null, "
            + COLUMNNR + " text not null, " + COLUNA + " text not null, " + LAMP + " text not null, "
            + ARMOR + " text not null, " + LAMPSTATE + " text not null);";
```

However, you are searching for a id column and not a _id column

```
  public void updatePoint(int idPoint, String Serial, String Observation, boolean tir, double x, double y, int networkNumber, int intensity,
                            int ColumnNr, int Column, int lamp, int armor, int lampState){
        String where = "id=?";
```

Just change the where, from "id=?" to "_id=?"